# Import Google Earth coordinates with elevation and altitude?

Tags: google-earth

I'm trying to do an isometric vector image of buildings in Cardiff city, similar to this image:[image]

Google Earth's 3D cities feature seems to be helping me greatly, as I can screenshot an 'isometric' view of certain buildings and pretty much trace over them in Illustrator.

```
51°27'41.10" N 3°09' 43.25" W elev 11m eye alt 47m
```

These coordinates give a fantastic isometric view of one of the landmarks I'm doing, but sadly, when I closed and opened Google maps, the camera had snapped back to the default location. I tried putting those coordinates into Earth's 'omnibar', but it simply didn't recognise it. I kind of need that exact angle, because I want it to be the same for the other buildings I trace. How can I import that entire location?

Edging slowly doesn't work, because when you approach an eye alt of 11m, the camera swoops down into street view unless you're really, really quick.